# MySQL - Trouble running a script from an existing .sql file which should create a schema, its tables and insert all necessary data in Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Workbench 6.0 and am trying to import a .sql file. The file should create a number of tables, insert data into each of these and commit these changes. It's a sample file for a course I'm doing and I'm going to use it to practice writing queries. Nothing fancy.

I want to create a schema in Workbench, run this script and end up with a database containing these tables and all the data, however I'm having trouble doing so.

I've tried creating a new schema and using the Forward Engineer... option and modifying the script myself, but I keep getting an error message that  already exists.

I'm a complete beginner with Workbench so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm going about this all wrong.

Can anyone advise?

EDIT:

I'm now getting the error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
create table Debiteur (
debiteurcode        char(6)     not null,
naam            varchar(30) not null,
adres           varchar(40) not null,
postcode        varchar(7)  not null,
plaats          varchar(30) not null,
land            varchar(30) not null,
telefoon        varchar(12) not null,
fax         varchar(12),
korting         numeric(6,3),
primary key (debiteurcode)
);

create table Factuur (
factuurnummer       integer     not null,
debiteurcode        char(6)     not null,
besteldatum     date        not null,
leverdatum      date,
factuurdatum        date,
bedrag          numeric(8,2)    not null,
transportkosten     numeric(8,2),
betaaldatum     date,
primary key (factuurnummer),
foreign key (debiteurcode) references Debiteur
);
```

The problem seems to be in the second table 'Factuur'.

Comment: Just drop what already exists,if thats an option.Btw,thats too little info in this question,people cant help you other than guessing.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of information should I add so that people can help?

Comment: The error message and your script if it`s not too big and maybe your existing db details.Isolate the problem.

Comment: In MySQL Workbenc, select File -> Open SQL Script, then select Query -> Execute (Shift + Ctrl + Return).

Comment: The error message I'm now getting is 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key definition is incomplete. See the online documentation for ["Using Foreign Key Constraints"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for more details. You have no target column set.